# Validating two linked fields with jQuery Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have two select elements: hours and minutes. If one or both fields are left blank I need an error to appear. I have been using the errorPlacement function to place just one error, but when you correct that one field, the error disappears but the other field is still invalid.

I have tried various combinations of validator.addMethod but there are always issues where both errors will show, or no errors will show etc.

Has anyone faced this issue before? Or does anyone know of a way to detect and handle the errors in the correct way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which field is required in your example, but you may be looking for dependency expression for jquery Validation. For example, if you wanted to make minutes required only if hours has a value, you would setup the validation like this:

```
rules: {
    minutes: {
      required: "#hours:filled"
    }
}
```

If this is not your desired logic, you will most likely have to create a custom validation method. Is this the logic you had in mind?

For reference:

[jQuery Validation Dependency Expression](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression)

Edit:

Here is a custom validator:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("hoursMinutes", function (value, element, param) {
    return $("#hours").val() != "" && $("#minutes").val() != "";
}, "Please enter both hours and minutes.");

validator.settings.rules = {
    hours: { hoursMinutes: true }
}
```

This will make only 1 error message show up.

Edit #2:

Try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var validator = $("#form1").validate({
                highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                    $(element).addClass("invalid");
                },
                unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
                    $(element).removeClass("invalid");
                },
                groups: { time: "hours minutes" },
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    $("#errors").append(error);
                },
                messages: {
                    hours: { required: "Please enter both hours and minutes." },
                    minutes: { required: "Please enter both hours and minutes." }
                },
                showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
                    this.defaultShowErrors();

                    if ($("#hours:filled, #minutes:filled").length == 2) {
                        $("#errors label").hide();
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#errors label").show();
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#submitBtn").click(function () {
                if ($("#form1").valid()) {
                    alert("valid");
                }

                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .invalid
        {
            border: solid 1px red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="" method="post">
    <div id="errors">
    </div>
    <input id="hours" name="hours" type="text" class="required" />
    <input id="minutes" name="minutes" type="text" class="required" />
    <button id="submitBtn">
        Go</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, this would set up two different methods that displayed two different errors. What is required is both hours and minutes fields need to be filled out. If if both or either one is left blank, a single should appear but highlight both fields. When the user corrects a field, the highlight should remove, but because the other field is still invalid, the error should remain.

Comment: Thanks for you help.In the above custom method, the minutes field is not validated. And if I was to add the rule for minutes in the validator.settings.rules the error would show twice. This is the main issue.

Comment: I added another solution that I think will satisfy your requirements.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks for your help Troy *buys virtual beer for Troy* :D

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day!